# I want to re run a Thread

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, winapi, c++98

I'm implementing Java style thread in C++. In order to do that I have a Thread::Start function but my problem is that when I use it, it works fine only the first time for some reason once a thread instance call start it finish of but I can't call start again and neither call other thread's start function.

It's my thread constructor:

```
Thread::Thread()
{
    m_handle = (HANDLE)_beginthreadex(0, 0, &call, this, CREATE_SUSPENDED, 0);
}
```

Thread destructor:

```
Thread::~Thread()
{
    if (m_handle) CloseHandle(m_handle);
}
```

Call function it's use as a wrapper for Run function:

```
unsigned int __stdcall Thread::call(void* _this)
{
    ((Thread*)_this)->Run();
    return 0;
}
```

And it's my Start function:

```
void Thread::Start()
{
    if (m_handle) ResumeThread(m_handle);
}
```

And the code that have the problem is the following:

The clerk class:

```
struct Clerk : public Thread
{
    Clerk()
    {
        IsOnService = false;
    }
    void Run()
    {
        std::cout << this->GetId() << " receive new customer " << '\n';
        Sleep(2000);
        std::cout << this->GetId() << " has finished" << '\n';
        IsOnService = false;
    }

    bool IsOnService;
};
```

Service class:

```
struct Service
{
    Clerk*      clerk;
    Customer*   customer;
    Service(Clerk* c, Customer* cu)
    {
        clerk = c;
        customer = cu;
        clerk->Start();
    }
    ~Service()
    {
        delete customer;
    }
};
```

And the main function:

```
int main()
{
    int nClerks = 5;
    Clerk* clerks[] = { 
        new Clerk(), new Clerk(), new Clerk(), new Clerk(), new Clerk()
    };
    Queue<Customer*> awaitingCustomers;
    while (1) 
    {
        if (GetAsyncKeyState(0x43) & 0x7FFF) 
        {
            Customer* newCustomer = new Customer();
            awaitingCustomers.Push(newCustomer);
            while (!awaitingCustomers.IsEmpty())
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < nClerks; ++i)
                {
                    if (!clerks[i]->IsOnService)
                    {
                        Service* newService = new Service(clerks[i], awaitingCustomers.Pop());
                        delete newService;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < nClerks; ++i) delete clerks[i];
    return 0;
}
```

When I run the code above it only call Start function one time instead of call it every time in that I press 'c' key.
I need a c++98 solution thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the bad news is that you cannot restart a thread.  i.e. Once the thread has exited, it's gone forever and cannot be restarted.

The good news is that there are a couple of things you can do that give you effectively the behavior you want, anyway:

1) Call `WaitForSingleObject(m_handle, INFINITE);` and `CloseHandle(m_handle);` to clean up the old/exited thread, then launch a new thread the same way you launched the original thread (i.e. by calling `_beginthreadex()` and `ResumeThread()` and so on).  This logic can all be encapsulated inside your `Thread` class so that as far as any calling code is concerned, the Thread appears to be "restarted" (albeit with a different thread ID, if that matters).

or, alternatively (if you don't want the overhead of launching a fresh thread every time):

2) Never have your thread exit in the first place.  That is, have your thready-entry function do something like this (pseudocode):

```
unsigned int __stdcall Thread::call(void* _this)
{
   while(timeToQuit == false)
   {
      // Do the normal Thread thing
      ((Thread*)_this)->Run();

      EnterCriticalSection(...);
      // we'll block here until the main thread wakes us up 
      SleepConditionVariableCS(...);
      LeaveCriticalSection(...);
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Then whenever your main thread wants to "restart" the internal thread, it would call [WakeConditionVariable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/synchapi/nf-synchapi-wakeconditionvariable?redirectedfrom=MSDN) on the Thread object's condition-variable to wake the internal thread out of its post-run sleep, and then the internal thread would call `Run()` again.  (And if you want the internal thread to quit, you'd do the same thing except set `timeToQuit` to true first -- not that `timeToQuit` should be a `std::atomic<bool>` or similar in order to be thread-safe)

Comment: Thx may u can help me with the entire project. I need to implement a Clerk-Customer program using Monitors and the Monitor, Clerk and Customer need to be threads. Can u give me some basic idea of what I need. And the most big problem is that I need to implent it using c++98 and for these reason I don't have an std::atomic class

Comment: In that case you can use a regular (non-atomic) boolean, but to ensure reliability you'll need to serialize access to it using a Critical Section or a mutex.  I won't try to help with general program design since this isn't the appropriate forum for that.